# How to get Horizontal Progressbar with text in android

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-custom-view

I want to acheive horizontal progressbar with text to update the steps to be completed in android.but i don't know how to acheive it.[image: **enter image description here**]

Answer (score 2):

Finally i found an library that suits my needs.That library is available in GitHub:https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/SnappingSeekBar

Comment: You can accept your own answer . Happy coding .

Answer (score 2):

**@IND VISA :**

> A SeekBar is an extension of ProgressBar that adds a draggable thumb.
>   The user can touch the thumb and drag left or right to set the current
>   progress level or use the arrow keys. Placing focusable widgets to the
>   left or right of a SeekBar is discouraged.

You can customize this Seek bar

1. [Android-comboseekbar](https://github.com/karabaralex/android-comboseekbar)

Answer (score 1):

you can use seek bar with background image

please see this

https://www.informaticscentre.co.uk/blog/implementing-a-seekbar-with-stepped-intervals-in-android

Comment: if don't mind can you add sample code of it...

Comment: library which you find is more suitable

Comment: Thanks for your answer and response.but i found an library it provides exact solution.